# Как записать двуменый массив в вектор? С++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Выдаёт ошибку: vector subscript out of range. Никак не могу найти ошибку. Помоги пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> undef;

void undefMatrix( int col) {
    int i, j, n, row2, k, p, c;
    row2 = pow(2, col);
    int binary[11][1025];
    for (i = 1; i <= col; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= row2; j++)
            binary[i][j] = 0;

    for (j = 1; j <= col; j++)
    {
        k = row2 / (pow(2, j));
        p = 0;
        c = 0;
        for (i = k + 1; i <= row2; i++)
        {
            if (p<k)
            {
                binary[j][i] = 1;
                p++;
            }
            else if (c<k - 1)
            {
                binary[j][i] = 0;
                c++;
            }
            else
            {
                p = 0;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
    } 
     undef.resize(col);
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        undef[i].resize(row2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
        for (int j = 1;  j <= row2; j++) {      
            undef[i][j] = binary[i][j];
        }
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < undef.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < undef[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << undef[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }  
}
int main() {
    int col;
        cout << "Enter number of columns of matrixes: ";
    cin >> col;
    undefMatrix(col);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да у вас какой-то бред написан. Почему вы колонки называете row2, а строки col?! В одном цикле вы используете условие i <= col , в другом i < col. Вы уж разберитесь, что есть что.

Comment: Чтобы заполнить таблицу истинности, сначала её переворачиваю и заполняю построчно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас предпоследний цикл двойной идёт от 1 до col (включительно) и от 1 до row2 (включительно). А вектор размера col на row2. У него нет элемента undef[col][row2] и вообще никаких элементов дальше undef[col-1][row2-1].

Когда вы пишите vector.resize(5) это значит выделить память (минимум) под пять элементов и предоставить вам доступ только к этим пяти элементам. То есть от vector[0] до vector[4]

*Если позволите, то ещё несколько общих советов:*

Зачем использовать статический массив вообще? Используйте сразу вектор.

Если вам нужно возвести 2 в какую-то степень, используйте битовые сдвиги.

Если вам нужно занулить непрерывный участок памяти (для C-style одномерных массивов), используйте memset.

Старайтесь избегать циклов, начинающихся с 1 при обходе контейнеров или массивов. Приучите себя начинать счёт всегда с нуля.

Не делайте глобальных переменных там, где в этом нет смысла (а лучше вообще никогда не делайте глобальных переменных).

Использование в цикле for метода std::vector::size лучше избегать, чтобы он каждый раз не вызывался на новом шаге. Выносите его из цикла, присваивайте значение переменной и используйте в цикле её.

Comment: В С++ вместо `memset` имеет смысл использовать `std::fill`/`std::fill_n`, хотя для многомерного массива он впрямую не применим.

Comment: ну по поводу size в for - тут спорно, компиляторы умеют оптимизировать.

Comment: @pavel да, я в курсе, но такая привычка. Это не только в for такое можно встретить и не обязательно size(). В общем, учит обращать внимание на лишние вызовы

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался